# How to avoid copy/paste of the adUnitId in XML for AdMob? For both test and release

Tags: android, admob

From the [official example](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  ...
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
```

They specify that one must use a test ad unit ID.

> When building and testing your apps, make sure you use test ads rather
>   than live, production ads. Failure to do so can lead to suspension of
>   your account.

How can I set the test and release ID somewhere as a constant? to avoid the copy/paste in every activity.
Should I create a layout for my banner?
But still, I would need to comment or replace manually the ID to switch from test to release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strings for it. Create two separeted directories:

```
app/src/debug/res/values/strings.xml
app/src/release/res/values/strings.xml
```

Place your `banner_ad_unit_id` there (for debug and release versions) and then use it in layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  ...
  ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
```

You can check more details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets)